# Haproxy as reverse proxy problem in ssl pathtrough

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I setup haproxy as reverse proxy in our organization . we want when the client request for some web site like lenovo or oracle or etc. …the request must be passed through our reverse proxy server .(because our client set our dns server and i defined reverse proxy’s ip as those such domain in our dns server). i using SSL passthrough .but i have some problem in this case.
1- some time haproxy doesnt work fine and have problem to load right certificate.for example when i want to see www.amazon.com haproxy load wrong certificate(SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN)  so firefox prevent to load  website. in this case i have www.intel.com in haproxy config so haproxy getting confused and load www.amazon.com with intel certificate website.
2-I want all sub domain of website like *.oracle.com or *.lenovo.com passed through our reverse proxy so we don’t need to register sub domains of website one by one in haproxy server .
i try with -reg or matching pattern method but all of them need to final destination.
3- some time redirection cant work properly and we facing http to https redirection error .(some time client enter lenovo.com or intel.com (means http requesting).to over come this problem i defined http frontend and redirect all request to https except one hypothetical request by acl . but my issue some time appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple done by req_ssl_sni and writing simple acl to forward request but attention to just write single forntend and backend ,because multi frontend and backend cause a confusing in haproxy.